# unable to download .zip Android emulator browser

Tags: android, download

hi
 if i try to download a book from the ebook store, my android emulator browser shows an error "Content type is not supported by the phone'. any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got following solution
-Download manager can be used(good choice is astro)  -or
-For application development it can be handled through code.